# Swift Universal Framework not working in other app project

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2, xcode10.1, ios-universal-framework

I created Swift Universal Framework and added external library via pod , but when i used universal framework in other app project,
It gives diffrent - diffrent error while compile the project like-:

1. "Missing required module 'Example' framework"
2. "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Comment: Hi Jain, you can check this repo as an alternative: https://github.com/gurhub/universal-framework, there is also a script for cleaning unwanted architectures from the Release bundle. Wich is your case I believe. Best.

Answer (score 0):

The error specifies that the symbols are missing for "architecture x86_64".
This could be caused when you tried to build for the Simulator and framework is not build for simulator.
Try building/compile the code for iOS device.

To support all the architecture, update the Framework build target.
Ref: https://medium.com/swiftindia/build-a-custom-universal-framework-on-ios-swift-549c084de7c8

Comment: I created "Universal framework" as per my knowledge that should be compile on simulator as well and when i trying to compile on device it gives me "Missing required module 'ReachbilitySwift' framework" error.

Comment: As per the error you mentioned. It seems like the framework you build have dependencies on Reachability Swift. You have to include the ReachabilitySwift framework to your app to resolve the issue.